# Delete everything from table based on it's referential data

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I currently have 2 SQLite3 tables in a DB. Once I remove one company name from Table1, I want to remove all the news articles assosiated with the company name in Table2. The code is in Python 2.7 using PyQt4.

```
if currentRow > -1:
    currentComp = (self.tableWidget.item(currentRow, 0).text(), )
    self.dbCursor.execute('''DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE comp=?''', currentComp)
    self.dbCursor.execute('''DELETE FROM Table2 WHERE comp=?''', currentComp)
    self.dbConn.commit()
    self.tableWidget.removeRow(currentRow)
```

This 2nd SQL Query is wrong. How can I make it delete multiple news articles based on the company name being deleted from the first table?

Updated with schema

Table2

INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, comp TEXT, pdate TEXT, ptime TEXT, title TEXT, link TEXT

Table1

INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, comp TEXT

Thanks and any suggestions or improvements appreciated. This is a personal project of mine to help improve my programming skills.

Comment: Assuming a reasonable table schema (where `comp` is a foreign key on Table2 referencing Table1), that second line looks like exactly what you want. Assuming an unreasonable schema… well, we'd have to see that schema, or know in what way the second query does the wrong thing, or ideally both, to have any hope of debugging it.

Comment: Meanwhile, if you're trying to percolate things manually like this, you usually want to delete the dependent rows first, and _then_ delete the row they depend on. That's the only way to guarantee that your foreign keys are always consistent.

Comment: Finally, why even try to write this code yourself, instead of using a foreign key constraint or an explicit trigger?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help... I will update my question now with the schema

Comment: OK, with that schema, your query should definitely be doing exactly what you wanted. It's not a perfectly ideal design, but let's forget that; your second query will delete all articles whose `comp` matches the one of the company you deleted in the first query. So, what's going wrong? A complete example (ideally with just a handful of rows), with the data before and after the queries, and the traceback if there's an exception, will be a lot easier to debug than "it's wrong".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, don't write this code at all. One of the reasons to use a database is that it can do all this stuff automatically. So, if you want to enforce consistency constraints, do it in the database schema. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Company (
    id PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name)

CREATE TABLE Article (
    id PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name,
    text,
    company REFERENCES Company(id) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

Now, when you delete Company #15, it will automatically delete all articles for company #15—or, if it can't do that for some reason, the whole statement will fail, and you'll get a clear error message and nothing will be changed at all.

---

If you really must do this manually, make sure to delete the articles *before* the company; that way, if it fails in the middle, you're not in a *predictable* state, but at least you're still in a *consistent* state. (And, since you were trying to delete all of the company's articles, the fact that you've deleted somewhere between 0 and all of them isn't that terrible.) If you need to be in a predictable state, do all the deletes in the same transaction. (Of course this still isn't as safe as letting the database do it for you, because you're relying on the fact that there are no bugs in the code you just slapped together, rather than relying on the fact that there are no bugs in the code that millions of programs are using.)

Comment: If you're going to delete them manually, use a transaction. That way, if something fails you can roll back your changes and be both consistent and predictable